# Posting to a form based on what HttpGet returns with Apache's HttpClient

Tags: java, forms, apache, post, httpclient

I'm posting data to a website form using Apache's HttpClient class. The form is retrieved using the following lines of code:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

The website that I'm retrieving the form from requires authentication to access the form. If the request isn't authenticated, the website redirects the request to a login form page that will subsequently redirect back to the original page on successful authentication.

I want to cleanly detect whether or not the GET request returns the login page or the desired form page so that I can either POST login data or form data. The only way I can think of to do this is by reading from the content InputStream of the entity of the response and parsing each line. But that seems somewhat convoluted. I haven't worked with the Apache HttpComponents api before so I'm not sure if this would be the only and best way to accomplish what I want to accomplish.

EDIT: To clarify question, I'm asking if there is a set way to handle forms with Apache's HttpClient. I somewhat know how to achieve what I'm looking to do, but it looks very ugly and I'm hoping there is an easier and faster way to achieve it. For example, if there was some way to do the following:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
if(parseElements(response.getEntity()).hasFormWithId("login")) {
    // post authentication data    
} else {
    // post actual form data
}
```

Because of my inexperience with Apache's HttpClient api, I'm not sure if what I'm looking for in the API is too abstract for the intent of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the behavior of the HttpClient by setting the HttpClient Parameters

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setDefaultHttpParams(client.getParams().setBoolean(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, false));
```

Which disables handling redirects automatically.

See also:

- [Automatic redirect handling](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1248)
- [HTTP Authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)
- [DefaultHttpClient API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

Comment: What would be the advantage in disabling automatic redirecting? I guess I was asking to see if there was an object oriented way to handle forms with Apache's HttpClient. I'll edit the first post to include an example.

Comment: If you disable automatic redirects for an unauthorized request you will get a response with `HTTP Status Code 30x` and target location in the `Location` Header. Depending on the Http status code of the response you can send the login information or even something else without having to parse the HTML content. A more "Object oriented" approach would be to implement a own [RedirectStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html). The Strategie would do something similar like the things I've described above.